# Youtube javascript load function

Tags: javascript

I created a load function in vanilla javascript so when you click on an image it create an iframe and play the youtube video.

Unfortunately is not working on IE8, any ideas what can be causing the issue?

```js
(function() {
    var v = document.getElementsByClassName("youtube-player");
    for (var n = 0; n < v.length; n++) {
        var p = document.createElement("div");
        p.innerHTML = labnolThumb(v[n].getAttribute('data-id'));
        p.onclick = labnolIframe;
        v[n].appendChild(p);
    }
})();
 
function labnolThumb(id) {

    return '<img class="youtube-thumb" src="../images/xmas-2015/' + id + '/thumb-video-01.jpg"><div class="play-button"></div>';
}


 
function labnolIframe() {
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.setAttribute("src", "//www.youtube.com/embed/" + this.parentNode.getAttribute('data-id') + "?rel=0&autoplay=1&autohide=2&border=0&wmode=opaque&enablejsapi=1&showinfo=0");
    iframe.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
    iframe.setAttribute("id", "youtube-iframe");
    iframe.setAttribute('allowFullScreen', '');
    this.parentNode.replaceChild(iframe, this);
}
```

```html
<div class="youtube-container">
   <div class="youtube-player" data-id="YWBPKZVJKkc"></div>
</div>
```

Basically it doesn't create the iframe inside the div just on IE8. no errors in the console and it works in any other version of IE

Comment: "not working" -> do you see any errors etc?

Comment: Yes, once you click the image disappear but it doesn't created the iframe for the youtube video

Comment: Open the browser developer tools (usually F12) and see if any errors are actually being reported.

Comment: No errors in the console :(